# Why do I get undefined for a variable that is initialized in higher scope and later in current scope?

Tags: javascript

Why do I get undefined for a variable that is initialized in higher scope and later in current scope?

Current code output: first "undefined" and second "i'm local".

Why is this happening? What is this problem and what is the name of this problem? What's the concept behind it?

```
var testVar = "i'm global";
function example( ) {
    alert(testVar); 
    var testVar = "i'm local";
    alert(testVar);   
 }
 example();
```

Comment: As it stands at the moment, this question isn't comprehensible enough to answer. Can you please re-write the question? Please don't use the word 'it' in questions, it's confusing.

Comment: Don't downvote, edit the question to make it more sensible, if reading between lines and looking at the code its obvious what the op wants.

Comment: @limelights questions like this are beyond redemption unless the OP clarifies it himself.

Comment: And yet there are 4 answers explaining what he wants. As said, I think you should edit the question instead, imo :)

Comment: @limelights and in those 4 answers, you have 3 unique interpretations of the problem.

Comment: All right, ill yield. Sorry.

Comment: The text of the question is indecipherable.  But the code provided exemplifies a classic problem in JS, which is the only reason it's  answerable.  And also why it should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @limelights fwiw I agree with you that this particular question could be edited to be answerable; I'm just illuminating the risk associated with it, as clearly several of our members would have gotten the edit wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You get only the local `testVar` because when you enter into the scope of the `example` function you have declaration of `testVar`, so you override `testVar`. In the first `alert` you should get `undefined`, because there's declaration of `testVar` but after that `alert`. In the second alert you get the local value because `testVar` is already defined.

To get the outer variable just name it in different way or pass it as argument:

```
var testVar = "i'm global";
function example(globalTestVar) {
    alert(globalTestVar); 
    var testVar = "i'm local";
    alert(testVar);   
 }
 example(testVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is equilivant of:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var testVar = "i'm global";
   function example( ) {
      var testVar;
      alert(testVar); 
      testVar = "i'm local";
      alert(testVar);   
    }
    example();     
</script>
```

So the first `alert` the local variable `testvar` is undefined. `var` get moved to the start of the scope.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `var` from the local variable. It makes the browser think `testVar` a local variable, which is undefined at the time of the first alert.
http://jsfiddle.net/N5Yf3/

Comment: hi @hart, can you the second question? the js-name for this problem?

Comment: @Max This is called variable hoisting.

Comment: @ahoff This doesn't explain why this is happening.

Answer (score -1):

try this it should alert both , u need to define first `testVar` inside function.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function example( ) {
        var testVar = "i'm global";
        alert(testVar); 
        var testVar = "i'm local";
        alert(testVar);   

     }
         example();     
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't really explain what was happening.